CPU frequency lower after wake from sleep
I have an old laptop Lenovo G530 with a T9500 with a fresh installation of 24.04. It works very well and when I put it in sleep and I wake it up, the frequency of the processor goes down each time to stabilize at 700 MHz and the computer becomes almost unusable unless I restart it. I looked a little but I can't find a solution, I'm a bit of a beginner and I solicit your help. thanks
Before sleep
After 1 sleep
After 2 sleep

I am so frustrated with ubuntu..don't know what to do..my bad luck I can't adopt mac os..the so called morons will be silent on these issues...
